# Every person plays with another in a tournament of $n$ people.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

It is called $k$-fair if for any set of $k$ players, someone beats everyone in thee set. Show that for all positive integers $k$ there exist $n$ and some tournament with $n$ people that is $k$-fair

My approach: Note $E(d^{+}(v_i))=\frac{n-1}{2}$, and there exist a graph such that the outdegree of every vertex is $\frac{n-1}{2}$ for all $n$ odd. There are $\binom{\frac{n-1}{2}}{k}$ $k$-tuples that are beaten by any vertex, and $\binom{n}{k}$ k tuples in total. Note for $n$ large, $n\binom{\frac{n-1}{2}}{k}>\binom{n}{k}$

So there doesn’t exist a k-tuple such that cannot be beaten by one person. Is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem with your solution is that a given $k$-set (not $k$-tuple, because order doesn't matter) could be beaten by more than one vertex. So just because you've found more than $\binom nk$ instances of a $k$-set being beaten by a vertex, doesn't mean that every $k$-set is part of one of those instances.

A $k$-set could be beaten by up to $n-k$ vertices, so you'd need $n \binom{\frac{n-1}{2}}{k}$ to exceed $(n-k)(\binom nk-1) + 1$, which isn't going to happen for any $n$.

---

Instead, consider a random tournament. Find the probability that a $k$-set is *not* beaten by any vertex, and from there, find the expected number of $k$-set with this property.

If the expected number of $k$-sets that are not beaten by any vertex is less than $1$, then it's possible for that number to be $0$, which would produce a tournament in which every $k$-set is beaten by some vertex.

Comment: Let $S_n$ be the set of vertices such that a vertex is in this set iff it beats $n$. I want find the probability for the intersection of the sets to be disjoint, which is clearly not 1.Does this work?

Comment: You've only defined one set, so I'm not sure which intersection you're taking. But I think more relevantly, you want to start by finding, given a set $I = \{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k\}$ the probability that some vertex $v$ beats all $k$ vertices in $I$, and then from there the probability that *no* vertex does so.

Comment: The chance for some vertex to beat one is $\frac{1}{2}$, therefore the desired probability is $1-(0.5)^k$. By what you have done, we’re done

Comment: There are $n-k$ vertices to consider, so you want $(1 - 0.5^k)^{n-k}$, to deal with a single $k$-set.

Comment: Oh thanks! I got it!